# How did this character fly this ship?

Tags: star-wars, droids, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *Star Wars Episode 9: The Rise of Skywalker*, Rey flies Luke's old X-Wing, which has been under water on Ahch-To for a number of years. Assuming that the ship didn't suffer enough corrosion or damage that it was unusable, how did Rey manage to fly, let alone navigate, to Exegol without the assistance of an R2 (or R4, etc) unit?

My understanding is that droids did most of the take off/landing of the ships, navigation, targeting, and so on, leaving the pilot to pilot the ship and make the instinctual decisions. I know Luke flew back from destroying DS1 with R2-D2 severely damaged, but that was a short flight in comparison.

Comment: She used the Force. Obvs

Comment: @Valorum Why look for the Wayfinder the then?

Comment: Luke went to Dagobah without using a navigational computer.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum a known planet in a know region of space though

Comment: have we ever seen water in the star wars galaxy or on Ach-To corrode whatever material an X-Wing is made out of? Pre-supposing a lot into those ideas ;) Also - that's not the first time that X-Wing has been under-water and flown again :D

Comment: Since Luke didn't have an Astro-droid when he traveled to Ahch-To, presumably he retrofitted his X-Wing with a cheap after-market Navicomp

Comment: Damage aside (although a few minutes under water on Degobah vs years under water on Ahch-To is quite different no...?) Luke knew where a was going, Rey didn't.

Comment: Plus Luke was using bits of the ship as his door

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - Luke had R2-D2 in his X-Wing to act as Navicomp.

Comment: @Valorum "That's not how the force works!"

Comment: Theres a big issue with the reliability question in the Star Wars universe - in Empire Strikes Back, Lukes X-Wing is submerged for a prolonged period in a swamp but flies afterward without issue.  In The Force Awakens, the Falcon hits the ground several times and even crash lands without issue.  In Solo, the Falcon is essentially crash landed and flies without issue.  And then we have Lukes X-Wing submerged in water (and indeed has a missing wing!) which flies fine in The Rise of Skywalker...

Comment: @Moo well it was a long long time ago, things were built to last back then!

Answer (score 15):

Although it's been confirmed ([repeatedly](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T-65B_X-wing_starfighter#Characteristics)) that the T-65B X-Wing Starfighter has no built-in Navicomp capability, we do know that Luke somehow managed to travel to Ahch-To without an Astromech droid given that we find R2-D2 rotting under a tarpaulin on Yavin IV.

Since the socket in the fighter is [seen to be empty](https://static2.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Star-Wars-8-Last-Jedi-Submerged-X-wing-cropped.jpg?q=50&fit=crop&w=740&h=370), the most likely option is that he retrofitted his ship with a simple [Navigation Computer](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Navigation_computer), noting that technology has moved on significantly since the days when Astromechs were required, to the point that even small First Order TIE fighters now have full hyperdrives.

It's also possible that Rey (scavenger par excellence) was able to cobble a working Navicomp out of components that survived the landing and subsequent bonfire of her TIE

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify the "repeatedly"? I see only one reference in the link you connected that word with.

Comment: @Marakai - It's mentioned in Star Wars: Ships of the Galaxy, Rebel Starfighters Owners' Workshop Manual, The Official Starships & Vehicles Collection (#02) and many other sources. This seems to be the agreed form of words;   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN2JB.png

Comment: Resistance X-Wing fights also have hyperdrives (at least from TFA and onwards), after Starkiller Base is destroyed they jump to hyperspace

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - It's not the possession of a Hyperdrive that's the issue, it's whether an X-Wing's hyperdrive can operate without an Astromech droid

Answer (score 2):

I wondered this myself, but then figured that the Sith wayfinder device was what gave her the co-ordinates to get to Exegol. After all, that was the purpose of the device.

Obviously, this leaves the problem of Luke traveling to Ahch-To without an astromech to calculate the hyperspace co-ordinates. So, as suggested by other answers, he may have had the ship retrofitted with a navicomp. Or, he may have used the Force.

Comment: Maybe Luke got a lift and just used his X-Wing to land?  I mean the map of where he went had to leak out somehow...

Comment: Alternately, the ship ended up in the water because he didn't have a droid to help him land.